# What is a best way to send message from tcp server to raspberry pi?

Tags: c, rust, tcp, raspberry-pi

I'm trying to use `REST API` server on my pi1 and `TCP server` on AWS EC2

I have `two raspberry pis` and as I wanted to use tcp server (in C) that I learned

(first one at home, second one at anywhere with wifi)

---

My goal is

if anyone (external) sends something on my pi's raspberry pi REST API server **INSTANTLY**

in an endpoint function, creates `tcp client` and also sending some JSON result to send somewhere

```rust
let mut stream =
    TcpStream::connect("ec2-XXX-compute.amazonaws.com:8888")
        .await
        .expect("connect failed");

// Buffer the bytes
stream
    .write_all(action.as_bytes())
    .await
    .expect("sending msg");

stream
    .shutdown(Shutdown::Both)
    .expect("shutdown call failed");
```

this client sends the message to EC2's TCP server and read with C language

```c
if ((client_socket = accept(server_fd, (struct sockaddr *)&newAddr,
                            &addr_size)) < 0)
{
    perror("accept");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

valread = read(client_socket, buffer, 10);
printf("From client: %s\n", buffer);
```

It works very well so far but what I want to do from here is to send the `buffer` data to

my another raspberry pi (pi2)

(pi 2's wifi keeps changing so it can only access internet, can't run server here)

What will be the best way to do this without delay or checking?

Sorry for the ugly picture but hope this helps your understanding

[image]

Comment: This is a bit of a vague question, but one option would be to run a message broker somewhere and have all parties who need to communicate connect to it. The pi2 would receive from a queue, and pi1 would send messages to that queue. The broker will hold messages in the queue if pi2 is offline/unavailable, and deliver them as soon as pi2 reconnects to the broker.

Comment: 'printf("From client: %s\n", buffer);' - you sure that buffer contains a NUL-terminated char array under all conditions?

Comment: @MartinJames I let it memset 0 thing to buffer to reset whenever it loops!

Comment: Ok, so the buffer is 11 bytes or longer?

Answer (score 0):

on PI 1, I'm running rest api/tcp server

and pi 2 can run tcp client server anywhere and connect to the pi 1

implemented with multiple clients without threading

Thanks all who watched this question!